# Writing new file in python 2.7

Tags: python

I have a very big text file that looks like this as below:

file.txt

```
    rs121334   6546
    rs42323    4214
    rs254532   5223
     .          .
     .          .
    rs42323    5223
```

where the first column is an rs number and the second column is a gene number. I want to write a code that searches for specific gene numbers in file.txt and writes the lines where those specific gene numbers were found in another set.txt file. I have the following code, but it is not working:

```
 dta=open("file.txt","r")
 w=open("set.txt","w")
 searchgenes=('5223','2645')
 for line in dta.readlines():
     line=line.split()
     for word in searchgenes:
         if word in line[1]:
            w.write(line)
```

When I run the code, I get `typerror`:

> expected a character buffer object.

Any help/suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: As the Input/Output documentation states, "To write something other than a string, it needs to be converted to a string first". so, simply change your last line to: w.write(str(line))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should work:

```
dta=open("file.txt","r")
w=open("set.txt","w")
searchgenes=('5223','2645')
for line in dta.readlines():
    rs_number, gene_number=line.split()
    print(gene_number)
    for word in searchgenes:
        if word in gene_number:
            w.write(line)
dta.close()
w.close()
```

It's better to avoid the re-use of the line variable and the in- and output files should be closed.

Comment: Suppose there is a gene 127 and 127065 in file.txt, that is, let us say that in the code above searchgenes=('5223', '127'). If I run the code above, then the output will also output results for gene 127065 simply because "127" appears inside the gene "127065". I only want the output to include the genes 127 and 5223. I tried to fix code by setting searchgenes=('5223', "\b127\b"), but it doesn't appear to do anything. Any suggestions?

Comment: You are right, I somehow assumed this is the intended behaviour. If one wants to check for identify a string comparison using "==" (instead of the "in" syntax) would solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You are using the variable `line` to refer to two different things: the line of text, and the list that results from splitting the line - this creates confusion. To write the original lines use a different variable for the list.

```
 for line in dta:
     words=line.split()
     for word in searchgenes:
         if word in words[1]:
            w.write(line)
```

Comment: Thank you! This really helped!